# Style is removed in cakephp email

Tags: cakephp, email-templates

I am sending email by cakephp 2.6.7. I use my custom template. But all style is removed except inline styling. Is it must to write inline style? I check the design before sending. it looks good. But when I receive email all design break. It looks like plain text. Any idea?

Comment: This has nothing to do with CakePHP, this problem is as old as HTML E-Mails, and depends on the client used to view them... **http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602400/html-email-in-gmail-css-style-attribute-removed** | **http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=email+html+styles** | **https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/** (CM has a _lot_ of good information regarding this subject).

Comment: You might also want to read https://github.com/dereuromark/cakephp-tools/wiki/Sending-templated-emails-with-CSS-and-inline-images