# Gmail added spacing between css & table tags text and braking html

Tags: html, css, email, gmail, html-email

In my html file everything is fine. But when i send email. Gmail add some spacing between css. Sometime remove css. sometime break html table tags.

[image]

Comment: Try to remove the space in spelling of `center`. Can you share the screenshot of your application?

Comment: Maybe you can find something in this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17602400/html-email-in-gmail-css-style-attribute-removed). [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38041282/4218046) looks like it may relate to this problem.

Comment: @MohitMaroliyaB17CS036 here is my application code

https://prnt.sc/1z4f2rn